Should there be the spacing between \dots and a closing atom in LaTeX? Why (and if so, how much) or why not?
On my machine, running pdflatex on
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% or mathtools. This leads to more horizontal space between … and }.
\begin{document}
\(\{x\mid \forall\, i\in\emptyset\mathpunct{:} \dots\}\)
\end{document}

yields
{ | ∀  ∈ ∅: ...}

or, as an image,

If you include amsmath or mathtools, you get more horizontal space between ... and }:
{ | ∀  ∈ ∅: ... }

or, as an image,

Any rationale?  Is this increase of space a bug or a feature?  Should there be any horizontal spacing in “… ClosingAtom”? Why or why not? In the positive case, how much? I found nothing in amsldoc.pdf on this.
(The TeX Book says that \dots in math mode is \ldots, but this is only mildly useful here as we are talking about LaTeX. Also, this question does NOT concern \ldots, which yields the same or at least very similar spacing regardless of whether we include amsmath/mathtools.)

off-topic: I don't think there should be a space between \forall and i. the i belong with the \forall ...

I believe there are some difficulties concerned with dots, amsmath and LaTeX. I don't know if they are related here. I only know that they rolled back a change which had various unintended side-effects a few days after the November release. If you look at the definitions, \dots expands to something enormously complicated once amsmath is loaded. whereas without amsmath, the definition is far more intelligible.

It seems that you used \unicodeellipsis instead three dots. See also section 2.6 in this document where the typographic conventions are mentioned too.

@cfr No to your off-topic aside. Logically, a formula starting with a quantifier has the form
Q [comma-separated list of sorted variables]: subformula ,
where Q is ∀ or ∃, and each list item is of the form variable ∈ sort.  The folks in my field consider it natural to separate Q from the following list as the list may contain spaces itself, e.g., as in ∀  ∈ Fset ,  ∈ Seq (Seq ): (,).
As for your second remark, good to know, thx!

@wipet I have not checked what \dots is expanded to internally by amsmath in this case. For the purpose of this question, we are fine with either of the three-dots-string ... and the single-character ellipsis … provided they look the same (i.e., the inter-dot spacing is the same). In this question, we ask about the legitimacy of space afterwards if a closing atom follows (here, the terminator of the set comprehension). The conventions in § 2.6 of the document you cite don't mention the case … ClosingAtom.

@AlMa1r You can see (from cited document) that the \unicodeellipsis gives different inter-dot spacing than \dots. You don't show the exact result, so I don't know what you are using. I suppose that you are using  \unicodeellipsis because you show  … and not .... If you accept the  …, then the question on spacing around it is irrelevant because inter-dot spacing is bad.  If \dots is common plain TeX \dots then \{xyx\dots\} looks right.

interesting. in logic, \forall x <some formula involving x and y> is not the same as \forall x \forall y <same formula involving x and y>. the first has a free variable whereas the second doesn't. logically, that's an important distinction, but probably such mixtures are implicitly disallowed in the literature you're interested in.

@cfr I never claimed that \forall x <some formula involving x and y> would be the same as \forall x \forall y <same formula involving x and y>. Both are valid formulas in my field, whereas the second is sometimes converted to ∀ , : <formula involving  and >, omitting the sorts of  and  (for whatever reason, e.g., for readability or inference).

@cfr Of course, your exemplary formulas are considered valid only if you are allowed to omit the sorts (in other terminology, the types) of the variables and the middle separator. In my field, we (not always but usually) use a middle separator between the variable list and the subformula (in my example here, the colon :; sometimes folks use the Z spot ⦁ or the double colon ::), whereas you use no middle separator at all.

@wipet My example does NOT say \unicodeellipsis. I think you mean to look into what \dots expands to. I have not checked this thouroughly; it is also subject to change IMHO. As of now, the PDF on my machine contains the three dots; I repaired the question text in this regard. I think this is a point to improve; we should really see the ellipsis … in the text layer because this would be semantically right. In any case, from the viewpoint of the user, which chars go into the PDF (... or …) is orthogonal to the question of spacing.

@AlMa1r Now is your question clearer (with presented images and with notice that the behavior depends on usage of a LaTeX package). My answer is: the additional space in this case (before })  is bug. The space between ∀ and  is bug too.

@AlMa1r it wasn't intended as a criticism ;). the types aren't omitted in my formulae. the language is rather at a different level of generality/abstraction. the example is from (some language defining) the predicate calculus, which is rather restrictive and not very expressive, so it makes relatively few assumptions but can say relatively few things.

@wipet The space between ∀ and  is intentional: it is usually used in the papers and, at least in the books I read or typeset, by definition.

The \dots command with amsmath doesn't just print ellipsis dots, because it wants that \dots is “context aware” so low or centered dots are printed as the house style requires. The default style is the one used for AMS publication.
Basically there are \dotsb (between binary operation or relation), \dotsc (between commas), \dotsm (between factors in a multiplication), \dotsi (between integrals) and \dotso (other cases) which can be customized by a class/package writer. Such commands are available to the user for usage when the type cannot be deduced from the context. For instance one has to type
a,b,\dots,k,\dotsc
a+b+\dots+k+\dotsb

when the dots are in the trailing position, because the test made by \dots would likely fail to guess the context. In your case \dotso is chosen which eventually prints low dots and a thin space.
However, this is a case where the dots are “trailing” and the user should help amsmath in making the correct decision. And in most cases, amsmath chooses to add the thin space.
You still have the possibility to use \cdots or \ldots; in the former case a thin space is added anyway.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\(
\{x\mid \forall\, i\in\emptyset\mathpunct{:} \dots\}
\) (dots)

\(
\{x\mid \forall\, i\in\emptyset\mathpunct{:} \dotsb\}
\) (dotsb)

\(
\{x\mid \forall\, i\in\emptyset\mathpunct{:} \dotsc\}
\) (dotsc)

\(
\{x\mid \forall\, i\in\emptyset\mathpunct{:} \dotsi\}
\) (dotsi)

\(
\{x\mid \forall\, i\in\emptyset\mathpunct{:} \dotsm\}
\) (dotsm)

\(
\{x\mid \forall\, i\in\emptyset\mathpunct{:} \dotso\}
\) (dotso)

\(
\{x\mid \forall\, i\in\emptyset\mathpunct{:} \cdots\}
\) (cdots)

\(
\{x\mid \forall\, i\in\emptyset\mathpunct{:} \ldots\}
\) (ldots)

\end{document}


You could try and change the style. Not for the faint of heart, though.

I was waiting for you answer. Happy to see you again.

@jlab Thanks. Let's say that I tried to test the resistance of my shinbone and the experiment resulted in ,

We missed you, it's always a pleasure to read your answers. Get well soon.

Thank you! Get better!

With amsmath \dots performs lot of tests to adapt its output to the context and usually add a thin space after it (these tests are done by the \mdots@@ macro, but it's too cryptic for me).
There is no thin space if all tests fail, for example if you hide the bracket behind a macro with \def\testmacro{\}} or if you add \relax just after \dots. You can also force the class with\mathclose (but I guess in this case also all tests fail), or use directly \ldots.
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% or mathtools. This leads to more horizontal space between … and }.
\begin{document}

\def\testmacro{\}}

$A \dots\smash{\rule[-5.3\baselineskip]{0.1pt}{6\baselineskip}} B$

$A \dots \}$

$A \dots \testmacro$ : hide the bracket behind a macro

$A \dots\relax \}$ : with \texttt{\textbackslash relax}

$A \dots \mathclose{\}}$ : force \texttt{\textbackslash mathclose}

$A \ldots \}$ : with \texttt{\textbackslash ldots}

\end{document}


